# How to implement comment facebook in application cordova

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

We have developed a cordova application and we want to put the facebook comment on an article .
For the commentary facebook, we have created a facebook application using OpenGraph
The application facebook has not been validated and facebook proposes to use the comments plugin: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/.

After some test, it's not a good solution because after connection, it can not return to the application on cordova.

Is there another way to make comment facebook in cordova ?

Rivo .